# How to rank each item based on columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to rank each Item, based on their columns in the following example.

For each Item, all elements are present in LC1 that should be Ranked-1, in LC2  it would be Ranked-2, in LC3 it would be Ranked-3 and in LC4 it would be Ranked-4

Input:

```
     Item   LC1     LC2     LC3    LC4
1   0A2926  MW92    RM11    RS11    WK14
2   0A2926  MW92    RM11    RS11    WK15
3   0A2926  MW92    SE92    NA      NA
4   0A3721  RM11    MW92    NA      NA
5   0A4664  MW92    RM11    RS11    NA
```

Output:

```
 Item    LC     Rank 
0A2926   MW92     1
0A2926   RM11     2
0A2926   SE92     2
0A2926   RS11     3
0A2926   WK14     4
0A2926   WK15     4
0A3721   RM11     1
0A3721   MW92     2
0A4664   MW92     1
0A4664   RM11     2
0A4664   RS11     3
```

Can someone guide me how to proceed on this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to `gather` data to long format removing `NA` values and to get `Rank` remove the character values present in the column so only the numbers remain.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  tidyr::gather(Rank, value, starts_with("LC"), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Rank = as.integer(gsub("[A-Z]", "", Rank)))


#     Item Rank value
#1  0A2926    1  MW92
#2  0A2926    1  MW92
#3  0A2926    1  MW92
#4  0A3721    1  RM11
#5  0A4664    1  MW92
#6  0A2926    2  RM11
#7  0A2926    2  RM11
#8  0A2926    2  SE92
#9  0A3721    2  MW92
#10 0A4664    2  RM11
#11 0A2926    3  RS11
#12 0A2926    3  RS11
#13 0A4664    3  RS11
#14 0A2926    4  WK14
#15 0A2926    4  WK15
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tidyverse` package like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% gather(Rank, LC, -Item) %>%
  mutate(Rank = as.numeric(grep("[0-9]", Rank, value = T))) %>%
  select(Item, LC, Rank)
```